# Why use function to create a data structure instead of class? Is it even correct?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I had compared the code that i found online and what my lecturer gave me. I am confused that why my lecturer uses function to create data structure instead of class like what i found online. Which one is better? class? function?

This is the code from my lecturer to create a stack

```
var Stack = function(){
    //Class members
    this.count = 0;
    this.storage = {};

    //Add item
    this.push = function(value){
        this.storage[this.count] = value;
        this.count++;
    }
    //Delete item
    this.pop = function(){
        if(this.count === 0){
            return undefined;
        }
        this.count--;
        var result = this.storage[this.count];
        delete this.storage[this.count];
        return result;
    }

    //Return the sie of the stack
    this.size = function(){
        return this.count;
    }

    //View the top of the stack
    this.top = function(){
        return this.storage[this.count-1];
    }
}
```

This is the code from my lecturer to create a linked list

```
function Queue(){
    this.collection = [];

    //Print the collection
    this.print = function(){
        document.write(this.collection + "<br/>");
    };

    //Add item in queue
    this.addQ = function(element){
        this.collection.push(element);
    };

    //Remove item at the front
    this.deQ = function(){
        return this.collection.shift(); //Left shift
    };

    //Return first item
    this.front = function(){
        return this.collection[0];
    };

    //Return the size of queue
    this.size = function(){
        return this.collection.length;
    };

    //Check the queue status: Empty or not
    this.isEmpty = function(){
        return (this.collection.length === 0);
    };
}
```

Just a few questions

1. why use function instead of class?
2. why use `var Stack = function(){` for stack and `function Queue(){` for queue? any different?
3. why use `this.push = function(value){`? i thought it should be function like `function push(){`

Comment: Hey just so you know, in real javascript, you're probably never going to write your own stack or queue classes because the built in array already acts like a stack and a queue. Your lecturer is just using them as examples.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is a prototype based language, so it doesn't have real classes. However, ES6 added the `class` keyword, which is easier to read, but still uses prototypes under the hood.

Everything in javascript is an object, including functions. When you call a function using the `new` keyword, it creates a new object and attaches it to `this` inside that function. So in your constructor, you can do `this.foo = function(){` to attach a function to your new object. However, this is inefficient because it runs every time you create a new object. A better way is to use prototypes, so that you only create each function once:

```
var Stack = function() {
    // Initialize local variables.
    this.count = 0;
    this.storage = {};
}

// Attach class methods
Stack.prototype.foo = function() { ... }
Stack.prototype.bar = function() { ... }

// Create instance of class.
var myStack = new Stack();
```

Since the `class` keyword was added recently, you'll need to use the functional way if you want to support IE11 or other older browsers, unless you're using a transpiler.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there's no difference in the two ways used, they work just the same way.
Also `this.push = function(value){ ... }` is how you define methods in Javascript